# plotting in matlab, increase number of divisions on Xaxis

Tags: matlab

I want to increase number of tickmarks on the `X`-axis in a Matlab Dft graph (magnitude vs. frequency). The precision is OK, but I'd like to increase the number of values displayed on the `X`-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the `XTick` property of the current axis (`gca`, get current axis), use:

```
set(gca,'XTick',tickVector);
```

with `tickVector` being a vector containing the desired tick positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by turning on minor tickmarks.

```
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on');
```

This saves you from determining explicit tick mark positions when you just want more.