# bar chart display all cateogries

Tags: matlab

I have a bar chart. It has 25 bars all representing a different category. The chart is fine however it only prints out a few of the categories.

I thought by using the line below that it would display all 25 categories that I have specified in x_labels.

```
set(gca,'XtickL',x_labels);
```

I also use the method rotateXLabel and rotate the labels 90 degrees so they are not over writing each other. However still only display some of the categories. How can I display all of them?

**update**

Here is my data,

```
'Health Care'   4.72629799981083
'Capital Goods' 4.09458147368759
'Transp'    3.98149295925542
'Media' 1.79439005788530
'Insurance' 1.69956150439052
'Commer Serv'   1.39773924375053
'Food & Staples'    1.37870312358688
'Tech Hardw'    1.14006008338028
'Div Finan' 1.07437424540054
'Retailing' 0.799227696500581
'Cons Durab'    0.484704646767555
'Semiconduct'   -0.0668927175281457
'Cons Serv' -0.0994263844790881
'Software'  -1.13770277184728
'Auto&Comp' -1.14193637823934
'Materials' -1.52052729345776
'Real Estate'   -1.58166267932780
'HH & Prod' -1.68076878183555
'Food Bever'    -1.73283367572542
'Pharma'    -1.90119783888618
'Telecom'   -2.04480219189470
'Utilities' -2.20510498991084
'Energy'    -2.36405808621777
'Banks' -5.09421924506606
```

**another update**

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517098/setting-a-specific-number-of-tick-marks-on-matlab-plot). Its not quite 100% perfect though as some of my labels are too long so the chart cuts them off. Need to work out how to get round that issue

```
 [pp,h1,h2]=plotyy((1:length(risk_tot)),risk_tot,(1:length(risk_tot)),risk_cont,'bar','stem');
 xData = get(h1,'XData');
 set(gca,'Xtick',linspace(xData(1),xData(end),length(x_labels(:, 1))));
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

`value` is vector with the provided values
`label` is a cell with the provided strings

```
bar(value);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(value))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', label)
grid on
rotateXLabels(gca(), 90)
```

[image]

Comment: yes that is what I'm after. I'm using plotyy as I have another series on the chart. I'm wondering if by using plotyy rather than bar has something to do with my labels being truncated?